# Change a cell value when validation updates

Tags: excel, auto-update, vba

I am having trouble making a cell value change on a cell change. Basically when the validation `Range("F112")` changes and the value is `<> "Lease"` then `Range"("F108")` need to change to `0`.

So far i have come up with:

Module

```
Sub SetLeaseToZero()

Dim Settlement As Integer
Settlement = Sheets("HV.Select Pricing").Range("F108")

If Sheets("HV.Select Pricing").Range("F112") <> "Lease" Then
Settlement = 0
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Sheet Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F112")) Is Nothing Then
SetLeaseToZero
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: first you need to add `Call SetLeaseToZero` so it will call your Sub

Comment: @ShaiRado That's not correct. `SetLeaseToZero` suffices to run that sub. Try it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the settlement object in order to change the value.  Adjust your module code as shown:

```
Sub SetLeaseToZero()

Dim Settlement As Range
Set Settlement = Sheets("HV.Select Pricing").Range("F108")

If Sheets("HV.Select Pricing").Range("F112").Value <> "Lease" Then
    Settlement.Value = 0
End If

End Sub
```

Note that the `.Value` calls aren't technically necessary, but they help clarify the code.